# How to calculate percentage of width from value between min and max numbers?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with simple problem. What is elegant way of achieving this.

I have 2 values **minimum** and **maximum** which can be **positive** or **negative** and a third value which is between them. Now I want to calculate `position(percentage)` of other given **number**, which in my case is the width of element.
For example  here I want to find what is position in the range 0-200 that represents value -10 in range -500 to 600 ?

```
var min = -500;
var max = 600;
var value = -10;

var width = 200; 

var positionInWidth = ???;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can one-liner this but let's do this in a few steps to see how it works:

[image]

```js
// first we get the total range
var length = max - min; // 1100
// then we offset the position by the start position
var positionInLength = value - min; // 490
// now we get the percent through the value is in the position
var valuePercent = positionInLength / length;
// or a one liner (value - min) / (max - min);
// Then finally, apply `width percentage`
const positionInWidth = width * valuePercent;
```

Or as a one liner:

```js
const positionInWidth = width * ((value - min) / (max - min));
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the so called map function. If that's the case, the implementation is as given:

```
function map(input, inMin, inMax, outMin, outMax) {
    return (input - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
}
```

In your scenario outMin = 0:

```
console.log(map(-10, -500, 600, 0, 200)); // === 89.0909090909091
```